# How to capture AAD landing page errors

Tags: adal

We are following the Single page application with ADAL.JS along with Angular.JS sample at the location: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js, this application is configured for multi-tenant. we wanted to track the exception which will happen in AAD landing page to AppInsights, for ex: like the errors "AADSTS50020" errors which gets showed on the AAD landing page. We tried hooking up the following events but they are not firing as the control is with the page https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf. Please suggest if there is any way we can achieve this ? (we are able to capture the successful logins as the control is returning back to our application)

```
scope.$on("adal:loginFailure", function () {
$scope.testMessage = "loginFailure";
$location.path("/login");
});

$scope.$on("adal:notAuthorized", function (event, rejection, forResource) {
$scope.testMessage = "It is not Authorized for resource:" + forResource;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adal.js did $rootScope.broadcast('adal:loginFailure') when receiving the errors during login. In your controller, if you listen on the 'adal:loginFailure', you should be able to get the error.

Comment: Thanks Wei, tried listening to the 'adal:loginFailure'  like below but its not firing. Please let me know if i'm missing any thing here?. Also as the AAD exception happening in page https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf and its not redirecting back to my app,  ADAL.JS and app.js is not loaded during that frame of time.

scope.$on("adal:loginFailure", function () {
$scope.testMessage = "loginFailure";
$location.path("/login");
});

Comment: Is the login.microsoftonline.con/login.srf displaying the error? If that's the case, since it doesn't redirect back, 'adal:loginfailure' won't be fired.

Comment: yes Wei, errors like for ex: errors like with error id "AADSTS50020": User account "" from external identity provider "live.com" is not supported etc.... which are displaying on the "login.microsoftonline.con/login.srf".  Is there any other way we can capture these type of errors?

Comment: If this is the case(not redirected back), ADAL.js won't be able to broadcast the error, and you will not capture it. But it's already shown on the login page, and displayed to user. Another way you could do is, set a timeout period, if within specified time, ADAL.js doesn't give you anything back, you know something wrong happend, But I'm not quite clear how you could get detailed error code back in this case.